# Where should I write the queries for Neo4j and where is the data stored?

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am going to build an application using neo4j for the graph database and expressjs as a platform for nodejs. However, this is the first time i am using Neo4j and I do not know where I should write my queries and view the data and where data is stored. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check out the documentation of the [neo4j node driver](https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/tree/v2#readme)

You'll see that you can write your queries either as part of service/helper methods or as part of your domain model.

The data is stored in a directory on disk, which is configured in `conf/neo4j-server.properties`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Micheal. I visited the neo4j node driver and I found that I need to install neo4j using npm, writing npm install neo4j --save.                And when I wrote it on the command line, there was an error saying that I need to include the following file with any support request: /Users/home/.Trash/neo4j-community-2.2.2/bin/npm-debug.log                          How can I include this file? :)